# Using form contents to add values to $_SESSION array

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to make a page that takes a form submission and adds the contents as a new value in the $_SESSION() array, what seems to be happening though is the value is being overridden.

The form has 3 text inputs named a, b and c and refreshes the page on submission. What tells me it's being replaced is $_SESSION[0] will display 1 2 and 3 as defined below, then the next row defined by $_POST will be the same but with the array values replaced by the last submitted values rather than adding the last submitted as another row.

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="text" name="b">
<input type="text" name="c">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['a']))
    {
     $a = $_POST['a'];
     $b = $_POST['b'];
     $c = $_POST['c'];
     $order = array('a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c);
     $_SESSION[0] = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
     $_SESSION[] = $order;
     $count = count($_SESSION);
     for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
      echo "w: " . $_SESSION[$i]['a'] . "\n";
      echo "h: " . $_SESSION[$i]['b'] . "\n";
      echo "p: " . $_SESSION[$i]['c'] . "\n";
      echo "<br />";
      }
    }
?>
```

Would be extremely grateful for any help,
Thanks

Comment: can you explain with an example what you want as a result? your text isn't really clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to add a new array to a new $_SESSION var each time the form is submitted. The method you are using will only add the value to the $_SESSION array for that page load - it won't actually be in the $_SESSION array! Confusing right? So either of these won't work...

```
$_SESSION[] = 'value or array';
$_SESSION[1] = 'some other stuff';
```

But this will, due there being text in the $_SESSION key (and don't forget to start the session).

```
session_start();
$next = count($_SESSION) + 1;
$next = 'foo' . $next;
$_SESSION[$next] = 'bar' . $next;
```

This will generate the below for "print_r($_SESSION)".

```
Array ( [foo1] => barfoo1 [foo2] => barfoo2 [foo3] => barfoo3 [foo4] => barfoo4...
```

Comment: You are a god amongst men! I don't suppose you have a link or anything explaning as to why the lack of text in the $_SESSION key was stopping it from working so I can educate myself and not run into it again? Thanks again.

Comment: Its to do with $_SESSION being a superglobal, and so every key must also be a valid variable name (i.e. $1 is an invalid variable). See the forth comment down here http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php#85147

Answer (score 2):

Most simplest way of adding form values would be

```
$_SESSION['form'] = $_POST; //once the form is posted
```

Then access the values using

```
$_SESSION['form']['fieldname'];
```

Comment: Okay that could work, but what about adding a second, third etc form submission, for example $_SESSION('form1', 'form2', 'form3'....) 
this is why I used $_SESSION[] so it adds each submission as another array of values but I don't understand why it replaces the previous values?

Comment: @Bigrob, Cant you assign different form names in session like `$_SESSION['frm_News']`, `$_SESSIOn['frm_artitle']`